# How to route every invalid request to a default path using node/express

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I'm trying to build a server that user will be able to enter these valid paths:

```
/art/thisProject
/art/thatProject
```

and in case the user enters anything else invalid such as these the user will be redirected to root and then to the default path `/art/myProject`:

```
/some/url
/something
/another/u/rl
```

I guess the error comes because of a false use of `"*"`or with false understanding of how to override router rules.

How do I do it?

this is my code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/art/myProject')
});

app.get('/art/:project', function(req, res){
    var project = req.param('project');
    var filePath = 'art/' + project + '/' + project;
    res.render(filePath)
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/')
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/')
});
```

Or this:

```
app.use(function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/')
});
```

Both must of course be put last.

Comment: cool! it worked! (only the second option). 1. what is the rational behind this? Why last and not first?

Comment: The middlewares are processed in the same order as they're added. So first it will check if the route matches "/", then "/art/:project", then redirect everything. If this middleware was put first it would match everything and thus redirect everything.

Comment: thanks! so we can say that after there is a first match it will not try and match different routes, right?

Comment: Exactly. Unless you call next() (the third argument provided to middlewares)